# Example of set of naturals without asymptotic density

Tags: natural-numbers

I read from Wikipedia that there are sets of naturals whose asymptotic density is undefined. How can this possibly be? Can anyone show me an example?

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/492719/39599) give some examples, but I think bof's answer is excellent.

Comment: The asymptotic density is defined as a certain limit, and in general limits can fail to exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the asymptotic density of the set of natural numbers with an odd number of digits?