# Do the subsets of $\mathbb N$ that have asymptotic density form an algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider $ \Omega=\mathbb{N}.$ Is said that a $E\subset\mathbb{N}$ has a [density limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) if the following limit exists:

$$\rho(E)=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\#\{k\in E: k\leq n\}}{n}$$

Let $\mathbb{F}$ the class of sets that have density. Is $\mathbb{F}$ an algebra?

Comment: See also: [If two sets have a natural (asymptotic) density, does their union?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133676) and [Sets with no asymptotical density over $\mathbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/492719).

Answer (score 10):

No, because $\mathbb F$ is not closed under even finite intersections. Hint: Carefully construct a strictly and quickly increasing sequence $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ of natural numbers and define $$C_k\equiv\{m\in\mathbb N\,|\,x_k<m\leq x_{k+1}\}$$
for each $k\in\mathbb N$. Let $A$ be the set of positive even integers in $C_1\cup C_3\cup\ldots$ together with the set of positive odd integers in $C_2\cup C_4\cup\ldots$. Moreover, let $B$ be the set of positive even integers.

Exercise: Show that $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ can be constructed in such a way that $A,B\in\mathbb F$ but $A\cap B\notin\mathbb F$.

Source: Billingsley's *Probability and Measure*, Exercise 2.18.

Comment: Consider an example sequence $x_k = 1000, 3000, 7000, 15000, \cdots, $. This would cause $\rho_n(A \cap B)$ to oscillate so that it never converges (where $\rho_n(E)$ is the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence under the limit).