# Exercise from David Williams' "Probability with Martingales" page 16

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, elementary-set-theory

I am reading David Williams' "Probability with Martingales" and I'm completely stuck at the exercise page 16:

*Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the class of subsets $C$ of $\mathbb{N}$ for which
$$\lim_{m \uparrow \infty}m^{-1}\#\{k:1 \leq k \leq m; k \in C\}$$
exists. You should find elements $F$ and $G$ in $\mathcal{C}$ for which $F \cap G \notin \mathcal{C}$.*

(I am able to find one subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that doesn't belong to $\mathcal{C}$, but unable to find anything like $F$ and $G$)

Comment: Should it be $m$ goes to infinity?

Comment: What if you "expand" your set $A$ that does not belong to $C$ by considering $2A$ (so all its elements are even), then consider $F$ and $G$ to each have limiting measure $1/2$ and $F\cap G = 2A$?

Comment: How do you define $F$ and $G$ to end up with a limiting measure $1/2$ ?

Comment: A standard construction for such a set is available in the accepted answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133676/if-two-sets-have-a-natural-asymptotic-density-does-their-union)

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact answer to my question