# Defining a probability on the natural numbers set

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, measure-theory

The standard definition of a probability on a set A is as a sigma-additive function from a sigma-algebra constructed on the power set of A to the extended real positive line (also called a measure), such that the measure of the whole set A is 1.

If A is the set of real numbers, such a definition cannot be made in such a way that any set consisting of only one natural number has equal probability, for, if mu({n}) = c > 0 for any n natural (where mu is the measure), then any infinite set would have infinite measure, and, in particular, mu(A) != 1.

But it is trully natural to think, for example, about the probability of certain events relating to the choice of a random natural number, such as the probability of getting an even number out of a random choice of a natural number, which would be 1/2. This kind of probability should satisfy the above condition of having odds 0 of getting any particular natural number.

I searched the forum and saw that many people work with probability on the natural numbers by relaxing the assumption of the probability being sigma-additive to just being additive. This seems to solve the problem, although I still didn't find an algebra and a probability function which would seem satisfying (but I guess it is not so hard).

The question, then, is what exactly one misses when relaxing the assumption of sigma-additivity. Does a definition of probability in the subsets of natural numbers via a finitely additive set function lead to inconsistencies? What theorems about probability stop applying under such a definition?

Also, am I being to restrictive in my general definition of probability, and is it acceptable in modern mathematical culture to define probabilities via only finitely aditive functions?

Answer (score 7):

> I still didn't find an algebra and a probability function which would seem satisfying.

It is tricky to describe this finitely-additive measure explicitly.
The naive approach would be to call $\mathcal{A}$ the class of subsets $A$ of $\mathbb N$ for which the "natural density" 
$$P(A) = \lim_n \frac{| A \cap \{1,\dots,n\}|}n$$ exists. Very nice, $\mathcal A$ is closed under complements, $P(\mathbb N)=1$, $P(\emptyset)=0$, $P($evens$)=P($odds$)=\frac12$, and in general $P(A^c)=1-P(A)$ for $A\in \mathcal A$.

However, $\mathcal A$ not closed under intersections ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133676/if-two-sets-have-a-natural-asymptotic-density-does-their-union) is a counter-example), so it is not an algebra.

In practice, people consider finitely-additive extensions of this $P$ to the entire class $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ of all subsets of $\mathbb N$. The extensions are usually non-explicit and use the strongest version of Hahn-Banach, which in turn uses the Axiom of Choice. A few references: [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2291075?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) [2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10959-007-0066-1) [3](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10959-015-0611-2)

> What exactly does one miss when relaxing the assumption of sigma-additivity? What theorems about probability stop applying under such a definition?

You miss everything related to limits, convergence, and infinite sums.

For example, let $A_k$ be the set of all even numbers greater than $k$ and all multiples of $4$.
This is a decreasing sequence of sets, and as $k\to\infty$ it converges to the set $A$ of multiples of $4$, but $P(A_k) \not\to P(A)$ since $P(A_k)=\frac12$ for every $k$ and $P(A)=\frac14$.

> Does a definition of probability in the subsets of natural numbers via a finitely additive set function lead to inconsistencies?

No. It leads to a theory that is less powerful than measure theory, but not inconsistent.

> Is it acceptable in modern mathematical culture to define probabilities via only finitely aditive functions?

Well, we would love to have a $\sigma$-additive probability measure $P$ on some $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$ that would coincide with the natural density for all sets $A$ that actually do have a natural density, but that's just impossible. People may argue that it will end up being less interesting since it will miss most of the theory, but if you have a good reason to study "uniform" probabilities on $\mathbb{N}$, that's all you got.

Answer (score 4):

> But it is trully natural to think, for example, about the probability of certain events relating to the choice of a random natural number, such as the probability of getting an even number out of a random choice of a natural number, which would be 1/2. This kind of probability should satisfy the above condition of having odds 0 of getting any particular natural number.

There is a standard way to ask and answer question like this, and it doesn't involve any measure-theory shenanigans. We simply calculate the uniform probability on the set $\{1,\ldots,N\}$, and then take the limit, if it exists, as $N\to\infty$. Using this technique, we obtain results such as: the probability of a random natural number being even is $\frac12$; also, the probability of a random natural number being equal to $112$ is $0$.

This doesn't directly address your question about additive measures that are not $\sigma$-additive, but I think it addresses the problem that led you to that question.